# Not sure why getting Syntax Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I'm following the online ruby on rails tutorial using an imac with OSx10.8 using rvm and ruby 1.8.7. When running bundle exec rspec spec/ I get these errors

```
/Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /Users/hetzerbr/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:88: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `run'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
from /Users/hetzerbr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

My user_spec.rb file looks like this, I think the error might be that I placed an end somewhere that I should not have or I might be missing and end somewhere:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
   it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }

    describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }

    describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end 
end

 describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
 describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com foo@bar..com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end

describe "email address with mixed case" do
    let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

    it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
      @user.email = mixed_case_email
      @user.save
      expect(@user.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
    end
  end

describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
      @user = User.new(:name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com",
                       :password => " ", :password_confirmation => " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end

describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(:email => @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your describe blocks don't have an 'end'

```
describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }

    describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }

    describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

should be..

```
describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a hash you must pass to the `new()` method while mass-assign , try it in `{}`

```
@user = User.new( { :name => "Example User", :email => "user@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" } )
```

at your error line : `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)`
`kEND` means end of file but `$end` means end keyword, you must close your describe do body of codes each by one `end`

Comment: That didn't fix it, I think I might be missing an end or have one too many somewhere... I'll post the entire user_spec.rb file

Comment: yes, I listed the errors in the first line of code and my entire user_spec.rb file in the second line of code

Comment: After adding the {} for 'new' method, did you save the file? the errors should not be the same!!!
And also your 2nd and 3rd 'do' doesn't have any 'end'!!

Comment: ohhh, to clarify, I need one end for every do?

Comment: ur wlc and tick my answer as correct answer then, you shouldn't update your error after getting the answer , you can post your new errors here in comments section if you want!!!! and try to count your 'end' and 'do' keywords , reread my answer , i edited some parts –